# Change button to Image in Copy to Clipboard - zeroclipboard-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, zeroclipboard

I Added Copy to Clipboard Functionality that working perfect but now I want to change button to Image. How can I change that?. I added simply image_tag but image comes on button tag.

Anybody have an idea How can I do this?

My script like

```
    <button class='my_clip_button' data-clipboard-target='fe_text' data-clipboard-text='Default clipboard text from attribute' id='d_clip_button' title='Click me to copy to clipboard.'>
      <b><%= image_tag("/assets/copy2.png") %></b>
    </button>
```

Comment: include img backgroud in my_clip_button class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into [rails view helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag) gives `The button tag allows richer labels such as images and emphasis, so this helper will also accept a block.`

Why don't you simply give the image_tag inside a block like:

```
<%= button_tag( :class => "button_green") do %>
  <%= image_tag("copy2.png") %>
<% end %>
```

**OR**

If it's a form then you can try [image_tag_submit](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/image_submit_tag)

```
<%= image_submit_tag("copy2.png") %>
# => <input alt="Login" src="/assets/images/copy2.png" type="image" />
```

**OR**

As mentioned in comment you can simply give `background-image` to your button and then adjust the image using *background-position* property

```
button {
  background-image:url("copy2.png");
}
```